# update table value and time stamp on click

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, button

http://www.ems-complete.com/peasi/dispatcher/dispatcher_screen.php

I am trying to make a button update a MySQL table when clicked need to change the value of the field.

ie. the initial value is 2 and when clicked will change to 3.

If possible would like it to be when I click the row get a pop up with more data and clickable options.

Here is the code I have tried

```
    <td><button type="button" onclick="<?php 
$row = $fetchselupcoming['id'];
$dispatch ='UPDATE incidents
    SET status=3
    WHERE id=$row' 
?>">Dispatch</button>  </td>
```

Comment: You may want to tag this for PHP and mySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can't embed PHP code like that, within the JavaScript onclick event handler.  Why not have the button as part of a form that submits to a page, possibly itself, then use PHP to update the MySQL record?